# Python predefined dictionaries or sets

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a question regarding Python's dictionaries or sets.

Are there any ***predefined*** sets or dicts you can use? I would like to have a set or dict for letters connected to numbers, like this:

```
{A:1, B:2, C:3,.....}
```

Is there already a build-in solution for this, or do I have to implement this manually? And if there is, where can I find an Overview over them? I have been searching for quite some time now, but got no result, but I am pretty sure I have seen this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no such predefined sets or dictionaries in the standard library. Their use is too limited and each algorithm would require a different mapping.

They are also trivial to produce for your code:

```
import string

{s: i for i, s in enumerate(string.ascii_uppercase, 1)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Investigate the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-constants) module for constants like `ascii_letters`, `digits`, `printable`, etc. You can then use the built-in `set()` and/or `dict()` functions (or comprehensions) to generate exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

```
import string

print dict(zip(string.ascii_uppercase,xrange(1,26)))
print set(zip(string.ascii_uppercase,xrange(1,26)))
```

Comment: this was helpful, thks ;)